# Incorrect URLs in Sitecore Habitat

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.2, sitecore-habitat

After a number of trials, I finally managed to setup Habitat for Sitecore 8.2

The instance name used is `habitatdev`.  I followed the git document on configuring these custom names in 3 config files in the VS solution.

The home page http://habitatdev works fine. But when trying to browse to any other page (say "About"), it goes to http://habitat.habitatdev/about.

This is with all other pages. I see there are redirection modules and solutions to create a new layout for redirections.

Is there any simple fix like a property in web.config where we can set the Items to navigate to http://habitatdev/[name] instead of http://habitat.habitatdev/[name]

**FIX:**
Open this config - `\Website\App_Config\Include\Project\Habitat.Website.config`

Look for the `site` and `cacheSizes` properties.

**Original:**

```
<sites>
      <site name="habitatdev" patch:after="site[@name='modules_website']"   
   targetHostName="habitat.$(rootHostName)" database="web" virtualFolder="/" .... />
    </sites>
    <cacheSizes>
      <sites>
        <habitat>
          <html>50MB</html>
          <registry>0</registry>
          <viewState>0</viewState>
          <xsl>25MB</xsl>
        </habitat>
      </sites>
    </cacheSizes>
```

**Changed to:**

```
<sites>
          <site name="habitatdev" patch:after="site[@name='modules_website']"   
       targetHostName="$(rootHostName)" database="web" virtualFolder="/" .... />
        </sites>
        <cacheSizes>
          <sites>
            <habitatdev>
              <html>50MB</html>
              <registry>0</registry>
              <viewState>0</viewState>
              <xsl>25MB</xsl>
            </habitatdev>
          </sites>
        </cacheSizes>
```

Comment: Do you have `targetHostName` set to `habitat.habitatdev` in your site config? Check `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx`

Comment: Yes that is right. I checked in Sitecore.config to find the same but it isnt there

Comment: `<site name="habitat" targetHostName="habitat.habitatdev" database="web" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content/habitat" startItem="/Home"...`

Comment: That's exactly the problem. Just set `targetHostName` to `habitatdev`.

Comment: I've also faced similar issue while configuring Habitat. Had raised bug on Github repo and it has been marked as closed. Here is the [link](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/issues/189)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem (looking at your comment) is in your site config.

You have:

```xml
<site name="habitat" targetHostName="habitat.habitatdev" database="web" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content/habitat" startItem="/Home" ... />
```

which means that when Sitecore generates url, it creates them using `targetHostName="habitat.habitatdev"` for their host names.

Just change it to

```xml
<site name="habitat" targetHostName="habitatdev" database="web" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content/habitat" startItem="/Home" ... />
```

and all the urls will be `http://habitatdev/...`

Comment: I am unable to find this property `<site name="habitat" targetHostName="habitat.habitatdev"` inside Sitecore.config. Will it be elsewhere?

Comment: Check `App_Config/Include/Project/Habitat.Website.config` or something similar in your project.

Comment: I found the property at `App_Config/Include/Project/Habitat.Website.config`. It was `targetHostName="habitat.$(rootHostName)"` and changed it to `targetHostName="$(rootHostName)"`...but now browsing the site thorws the error `Duplicate site definition: habitat`

Comment: I was able to fix it..I am updating my question with the fixes....Thank you very much Marek